# system.argumentoufofrange exception :lenght cannot be less than 0 (line 32) overflow exception( Line 29)

Tags: c#, websocket, console-application

Sup people im creating a program to listen to incoming string it works...well that which i have coded so far works the problem is if they send their string my program throws the argument out of range exception

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        using System.Net.Sockets;

  namespace Stringlistener
  {
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(my port number);
        int requestCount = 0;
        TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        serverSocket.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(" >> Server Started");
        clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine(" >> Accept connection from client");
        requestCount = 0;

        while ((true))
        {
            try
            {
                requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10000000000025];
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
                Console.WriteLine(" >> Data from client - " + dataFromClient);
                string serverResponse = "Last Message from client" + dataFromClient;
                Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
                networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                networkStream.Flush();
                Console.WriteLine(" >> " + serverResponse);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            clientSocket.Close();
            serverSocket.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(" >> exit");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }


    }
}
```

}

```
 String:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<faf>
            <hah>
                            <gr>00.00</gr>
                            <yy>000000000</yy>
            </hah>
            <ee>
                            <gr>00.00</gr>
                            <yy>000000000</yy>
            </ee>
</faf>
```

any ideas? is the problem from my side if so how do i fix it?
A good explanation and answer will be much appreciated i wish to understand this to stop the same problem from recurring in the future

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you debug your code? On which line exactly?

Comment: line 32 and yes always the problem is im working with another party to send the strings makes testing kinda difficult if they dont cooperate

Comment: the winforms program i built as clientside works perfect without any problems thats how i tested it so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String.Substring(int, int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) expects a starting index in the first parameter and a length in the second parameter.  `IndexOf` will return -1 if the search string is not found in the supplied string.

So your code:

```
dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"))
```

Is looking for "$" in the string.  If `dataFromClient` doesn't contain a "$", `IndexOf` returns -1, which then makes the `Substring` look like this:

```
dataFromClient.Substring(0, -1)
```

The documentation (linked above) states that an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is thrown when startIdnex plus length indicates a position not within this instance or *startIndex or length is less than zero.*

The length must be greater than 0, and -1 obviously is not.  Hence the error.

Comment: thanks for the explanation both answers are correct i just wanted a detailed explanation thank you

Answer (score 2):

The `IndexOf` call on line 32 returns -1 if the search string is not found.  Presumably the data from the client doesn't contain "$".

Comment: please elaborate @warrenG

Comment: i have a example of the string they are attempting to send if this will help?

Comment: @Wolf - Please edit your answer and add in an example of the string.